# I want to make a scrollable div on x-axis and y-axis in a builder and in that builder

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the screenshot of my page where I want to make this scroll functionality, so in this screenshot I want to make this functionality for the given paragraph of a `div` inside a blue line

[image: screenshot from page]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Add what you tried... And rather than a like to the image, add the image inline!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
<div id="xyz">

to

<div id="xyz" style="overflow-y: scroll;">

or you can write in your css or style tag in head as 

#xyz
    {
       overflow-y:scroll;
    }

This is working for me.
```